# Get value in column from raw

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

- table 1 has item name
- table 2 has item parameters

Item parameters can be multiple for same item.

Now I want output with these columns:

```
item name, item parameter 1, item parameter 2, item parameter 3
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, here is a link to help you post better quality questions:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

use `PIVOT` , it will help you , here is [the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)